# onTouchEvent works on one page but it doesn't work on another page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am new to Android, i tried to use an `ontouchevent()` to detect screen touch, i worked on one of the sample page but when i copy pasted the same code in another page it doesn't seem to be working.

I think it has something to do with the `View`.

Can someone please help me on this.

**Code**

```
public class HelpDesk extends Activity{ 
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
{   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.help);  
    ImageButton home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home);
    ImageButton exit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.exit);

    final Intent homeIntent = new    Intent(this,MobNavSys4VisuallyImpaired.class);

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            startActivity(homeIntent);

        }
    });

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            startActivity(homeIntent);

        }
    });
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
  System.out.print("touch");
    Toast.makeText(this, "hiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    return true;
}}
```

`

Comment: Add more details to it . Just mentioning that it does not work on the other page is ambiguous.

Comment: does your buttons still can be clicked?

Answer (score 0):

check it

change `return true;`
to `return super.onTouchEvent(event);`